# What is the new Firefox fingerprinter settings feature doing?

Tags: firefox, browser, html5, fingerprint

Firefox has a new function called fingerprinter (settings under privacy).

- I know what fingerprinting means, but what is Firefox doing exactly when this feature is activated?
- What data is being changed by this setting, as in both cases (active/inactive fingerprinter setting), doing a test on `panopticlick.eff.org` still results in receiving a uniquely assigned HTML canvas hash?

What exactly is Firefox "preventing" or "changing" by this fingerprinter setting then?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to a website that specifically uses a canvas to fingerprint you, like the Panopticlick tech demo, nothing will really change. That website isn't using a 3rd-party service to do the fingerprinting.

Essentially, Firefox can make the claim that it blocks Fingerprinters because that's a category that is used by [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me/). The Disconnect list [is what Firefox uses](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/content-blocking#w_how-to-block-more-or-fewer-trackers) to block trackers etc. Therefore, by blocking resources from those domains, they cannot possibly get the opportunity to fingerprint in the first place. Of course, any new trackers that haven't yet made the list could still fingerprint you.

Below is an example of what Firefox shows when it detects and blocks such a Fingerprinting tracker.

[image: DailyMail.co.uk contains a fingerprinter]

In addition to blocking domains that are known to track the user, Firefox does attempt to reduce your browser's uniqueness entropy in a number of other ways, many of which are [briefly documented on this security wiki page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Fingerprinting).

In my research, I also found this older article about [Firefox trialing a new permission to require user permission to use the canvas](https://thehackernews.com/2017/10/canvas-browser-fingerprint-blocker.html), although I'm not sure if that ever made it into the public release (it certainly doesn't seem to be present in the current version, probably because there are lots of legitimate uses for it).